# Unwanted navigationbar WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on some WPF app with a main window and with some pages, something weird happened to me, "suddenly" when I move from page 1 to page two this toolbar added himself to my window,

my questions: where did this came from? how to remove/ give it better design, I mean where is the source code of this toolbar

Is this default by Microsoft?

[image]

Here is my window class def:

```
<Window x:Class="Tool.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tool"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"       
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        MinWidth="600"
        MinHeight="500"
        Title="Preparation Tool" Height="600" Width="1080" Icon="icon.ico" Foreground="White" >
```

Comment: this is default if you use Frame with Pages. I think it can be disabled, if not, just use MVVM navigation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where did this came from? How to remove it?

It is a built-in navigation chrome in `Frame` control.
According to Microsoft docs, the navigation chrome is visible when a `Frame` uses its own journal (see [JournalOwnership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.frame.journalownership?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_Frame_JournalOwnership)).

If you don't want that Navigation chrome, you can simply set `NavigationUIVisibility` property of your frame to `Hidden`.

```
<Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
```

If you don't want history navigation management of the current `Frame` too, you can set `JournalOwnership` property of `Frame` to `UsesParentJournal` . This makes your `Frame` use the journal of the next available navigation host up the content tree, if available. Otherwise, navigation history is not maintained for the `Frame`.

```
<Frame JournalOwnership="UsesParentJournal" />
```

> Or give it a better design? I mean where is the source code of this toolbar?

In Visual Studio (or Visual Studio Blend that I prefer for UI design stuff) simply right-click on your `Frame` and then select **Edit Template > Edit a copy** and put copy of Template in a `ResourceDictionary`. Then you can modify the template which it's key is *FrameNavChromeTemplateKey*.

> Is this default by Microsoft?

Yes.

P.S. Do not forget that when you set `NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"` and `JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"`, history management for `Frame` itself is still available and you can navigate between pages with commands like Next/Prev mouse buttons.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily hide that:

```
<Frame  NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
```

But you should use contentcontrol instead of frame and usercontrols instead of pages.